# Arabic Text Alignment

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, arabic

[image]

I am using `UITextView` in **Swift 3.0** and I would like to support both English and Arabic language. When I am setting Arabic text in the `UITextView`, it is aligned left to right instead of right o left.

I have set the alignment to natural in storyboard but it is not working. I want to show text left to right in case of english and right to left in case if arabic text.

How can I achieve it in **Swift 3.0**?

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: @SandeepAgrawal..have you add arabic font in your project

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please see the attached image.

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad No I don't add any arabic font. Arabic text is shown here , Issue is with the alignment.

Comment: how do you find the language is changed

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't want to find the language, It should align the text as per device language. If it is english, align it to left to right and it it is arabic align the text from right to left. It should auto detect the device language and align the text.

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad  Not working. Still text gravity is left.

Comment: try this too:  myTextVObj.textAlignment = .left or .right   inside the if else condition.

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad It works with text alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
let currentDeviceLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode


if let currentDeviceLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode {
print("currentLanguage", currentDeviceLanguage)


if currentDeviceLanguage == "he" {
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
} else {
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
}
```

}